# Rails g bootstrap:install not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-rails

I am getting a problem running the command

`rails g bootstrap:install` as part of the `twitter-bootstrap-rails` gem.

I get the following error:

```
/Users/matty/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/therubyracer-0.8.2/lib/v8/context.rb:74:in `IsEntered': HandleScope::HandleScope: Entering the V8 API without proper locking in place (fatal)
 from /Users/matty/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/therubyracer-    0.8.2/lib/v8/context.rb:74:in `enter'
 from /Users/matty/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/therubyracer-0.8.2/lib/v8/portal.rb:74:in `open'
 from /Users/matty/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/therubyracer-0.8.2/lib/v8/object.rb:18:in `block in []='
 from /Users/matty/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/therubyracer-0.8.2/lib/v8/object.rb:17:in `tap'
 from /Users/matty/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/therubyracer-0.8.2/lib/v8/object.rb:17:in `[]='
 from /Users/matty/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/therubyracer-0.8.2/lib/v8/context.rb:56:in `[]='
 from /Users/matty/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/less-2.2.2/lib/less/loader.rb:12:in `initialize'
 from /Users/matty/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/less-2.2.2/lib/less.rb:14:in `new'
 from /Users/matty/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/less-2.2.2/lib/less.rb:14:in `<module:Less>'
 from /Users/matty/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/less-2.2.2/lib/less.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
 from /Users/matty/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/bundler-1.2.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
 from /Users/matty/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/bundler-1.2.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'
 from /Users/matty/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/bundler-1.2.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
 from /Users/matty/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/bundler-1.2.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'
 from /Users/matty/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/bundler-1.2.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
 from /Users/matty/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/bundler-1.2.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
 from /Users/matty/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/bundler-1.2.2/lib/bundler.rb:128:in `require'
 from /Users/matty/Documents/rubyboot/boots/store/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
 from /Users/matty/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:24:in `require'
 from /Users/matty/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:24:in `<top (required)>'
 from script/rails:6:in `require'
 from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Can someone help me to diagnose please?

Comment: I think its issue with libV8 can you install it first and try to install bootstrap?

Comment: Are you working on windows?

Comment: Wouldn't be on windows as it doesn't use the /Users mapping. I think cygwin uses /home if im not mistaken. Been a while.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the version of the rubyracer, that should also update libv8 from a dependency standpoint:

```
bundle update therubyracer
```